# How to do this query - GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-concat

I'd like to do a `SELECT` on `table A` which has:

```
table_a:

╔══════════╦════════╗
║ GROUP_ID ║  NAME  ║
╠══════════╬════════╣
║        1 ║ Tom    ║
║        2 ║ Frank  ║
║        3 ║ Shilla ║
║        1 ║ Scully ║
║        1 ║ Jen    ║
╚══════════╩════════╝


table_b:

╔════╦════════════╗
║ ID ║ GROUP_NAME ║
╠════╬════════════╣
║  1 ║ Troopers   ║
║  2 ║ Clubs      ║
║  3 ║ Mavericks  ║
╚════╩════════════╝
```

Now, I'd like to display the group given a name of the member:

```
SELECT GROUP_NAME,GROUP_CONCAT(table_a.NAME) MEMBERS     
FROM table_a     
JOIN  table_b ON table_a.GROUP_ID = table_b.ID   
WHERE
table_a.NAME = 'Scully'
```

I'd like to get this:

```
╔════════════╦════════════════╗
║ GROUP_NAME ║    MEMBERS     ║
╠════════════╬════════════════╣
║ Troopers   ║ Tom,Scully,Jen ║
╚════════════╩════════════════╝
```

Why does this query not work?

Comment: You're limiting your results to JUST Scully.  perhaps you just want to limit by SCULLY's group ID?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT  b.GROUP_NAME, GROUP_CONCAT(c.Name) Members
FROM    
        (
            SELECT GROUP_ID
            FROM   table_a
            WHERE  name = 'Scully'
        ) a 
        INNER JOIN table_b b
            ON a.GROUP_ID = b.ID
        INNER JOIN table_a c
            ON a.GROUP_ID = c.GROUP_ID
GROUP   BY b.GROUP_NAME
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ac1e65/10)

for better performance, add a `UNIQUE` constraint for `table_b.GROUP_Name`.

RESULT

```
╔════════════╦════════════════╗
║ GROUP_NAME ║    MEMBERS     ║
╠════════════╬════════════════╣
║ Troopers   ║ Tom,Scully,Jen ║
╚════════════╩════════════════╝
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your WHERE condition is too restricted.

`WHERE table_b.GROUP_NAME = 'Troopers'`

If you only have the name of a member then you'll need to get the group id using another join:

Try with this:

```
SELECT table_b.GROUP_NAME, GROUP_CONCAT(table_a.NAME) MEMBERS     
FROM table_a     
JOIN  table_b ON table_a.GROUP_ID = table_b.ID   
JOIN  table_b `temp` ON table_a.GROUP_ID = temp.ID   
WHERE temp.NAME = 'Scully'
```

Comment: I need to find the group given a member

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    `group_name`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(a.`name`) AS 'members'
FROM `table_a` a
INNER JOIN `table_b` b
ON a.`group_id` = b.`id`
AND a.`group_id` = (
    SELECT `group_id` FROM `table_a` WHERE `name`='Scully'
)
GROUP BY NULL
```